# How to only use server side validation if client form validation bypassed/disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/2/

And I am using jQuery/ajax for server side validation as a backup. The problem is that the server side validation first first. It is meant to just be a backup in case the client side validation is bypassed etc. How can I get it not to work unless needed?

```
<form id="supportForm">

$("#supportForm").validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            mobile: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength: 9
            },
            company: "required",
            'checkboxes[]': {required: true}   
        },
         messages: {
            first_name: "First name required",
            last_name: "Last name required",
            email: "Inalid email address",
            mobile: "Please enter only digits",
            company: "Company required",
            'checkboxes[]': "Select at least one service"
        }
});

    $('#consult').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#supportForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.error-message').empty().hide();
                $('consult').prop('disabled', true);
                $('consult').val('Submitting...');

            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if(!data.success) {
                $('.error-message').append(data.message).fadeIn();
                $('consult').prop('disabled', false);
                $('consult').val('Submit');


            } else {
                alert('success, process form');
            }
        })
         .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should have a look at the `submitHandler`:  [***"Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."***](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the server side validation fires first.

The issue here is that you're not validating your form before submitting it.

jquery validate hooks into the form submit, but you're manually serialising the form yourself (thus by-passing the browser submit).

You need to call the jquery validation `form.valid()` before your $.ajax.

```
$('#consult').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$('#supportForm').valid())
        return;

    var form = $('#supportForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({ ...
```

More info: https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: Thank you! How can I test that the server side validation is still in tact without manipulating the code?

Comment: Without manipulating the code?  Not sure what you mean.  You can remove the `.valid()` call, you could overwrite the .valid() call with `return true;` - but those are definitely "manipulating".  There are other ways to bypass the UI validation, which is exactly why you have server-side validation, but I would suggest all of them are "manipulating" the code or the HTML.

Comment: [Or you could have just used the `submitHandler` callback that was put into the plugin for this exact purpose. - *"Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)

Comment: @Sparky you should add your own answer, that looks like a valid option.  Don't know why you made it all one horrid long link though.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a separate `click` handler for your Ajax.  The plugin contains an option for this called [the `submitHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), and the click is already automatically being captured by the plugin.

> Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax
>   after it is validated.

```
$("#supportForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ....   
    },
    messages: {
        ....
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#supportForm').serialize(),
            ....
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that the function's argument is called `form`, so rename the argument or rename your variable.  There is also no need to use a `.preventDefault()`; again, because the plugin is already taking care of it for you.